# How to run WebServices in a unit test

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing

I created a function that verifies some rules. The function is supposed to return a bool whenever an element of a list matches an element of another list.

Here is the relevant code of the Rule Class

```
public override TestResult Execute()
{
      Instrument ins = (Items.Length > 0) ? Items[0] as Instrument : null;
      string errorInfo;

      if (ins == null)
      {
          Result.Message = "Unable to perform test";
          Result.Status = ResultStatus.Error;
          return Result;
      }
      if (MPICSupportDB(ins))
      {
          Result.Message = "DB not supported by MPIC";
          Result.Status = ResultStatus.Yellow;
      }
      else
      {
          Result.Status = ResultStatus.Green;
      }

      return Result;
}

private bool MPICSupportDB(Instrument ins)
{
    IServiceProviderFactory serviceFactory = new WebServiceProviderFactory();
    IInterfaceAssignmentService wService = serviceFactory.CreateInterfaceAssignmentService();
    InterfaceAssignment wAssignments = wService.LoadAssignmentGroup("R4");

    return ins.Connections.OfType<InterfaceConnection>()
                          .Where(conn => conn.Card.IsDB)
                          .Any(conn => wAssignments.PartMasters
                          .Any(partNumber => (conn.CardPartNumber == partNumber.PartNumber)));               
}
```

I am trying to test the function `MPICSupportDB` in a unit test. So far I have started creating my unit test (below), but now I'm lost and I have no idea what to do.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestForcompatibleDB()
{
    var ins = new Instrument();
    var serviceFactoryMock = new Mock<IServiceProviderFactory>();
    var wserviceTest = new Mock<IInterfaceAssignmentService>();
    var wassagnementTest = new Mock<InterfaceAssignment>();

    // adding an MPIC card
    ins.Connections.Add(AddCard(CardType.MPIC, "MA505400612268", "CARD1", 0, ins));

    // adding an MPIC daughterboard
    ins.Connections.Add(AddCard(CardType.GPIM_DB, "MA335022012268", "DB1", 1, ins));


    var rule = new Rule026(RuleApplicability.Test, new object[] { ins });
    var result = rule.Execute();

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(ResultStatus.Green, result.Status);

}
```

The problem is that classes like `Webservice` and `factoryService` cannot be run directly in a unit test.

Can someone explain to me how to properly mock these object and make my test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `IServiceProviderFactory` to your `Rule026` class, rather than constructing it within the class.  This will allow you to use your Mocks that you're creating.  The most common approach would be through constructor injection.  You haven't provided the Constructor for your Rule class, but if you modify it to something like this:

```
public Rule026(/*otherArgs*/, IServiceProviderFactory scpFactory = null) {
    if(null == scpFactory)
        scpFactory = new ServiceProviderFactory();
    }
    _serviceProviderFactory = scpFactory;
}
```

Then you will be able to inject the factory from your tests, whilst not having to update all of the code currently constructing Rules.  Moving to an IOC container to provide the dependencies, or removing the default and forcing the clients to create the factory in order to able to instantiate the Rule may be preferable, depending on your situation.

Once you can pass in your mocks, you just need to setup a return chain to allow the mocks to return each other.  Something like:

```
    var serviceFactoryMock = new Mock<IServiceProviderFactory>();
    var wserviceTest = new Mock<IInterfaceAssignmentService>();
    var wassagnementTest = new Mock<InterfaceAssignment>();

    serviceFactoryMock.Setup(x=>x.CreateInterfaceAssignmentService())
                      .Returns(wserviceTest.Object);
    wserviceTest.Setup(x=>x.CreateInterfaceAssignmentService())
                .Returns(wassagnementTest.Object);
    wassagnementTest.Setup(x=>x.LoadAssignmentGroup(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(cannedInterfaceAssignmentResponse);
```

And then supply the mock when constructing your object:

```
var rule = new Rule026(RuleApplicability.Test, 
                       new object[] { ins }, 
                       serviceFactoryMock.Object);
```

You may also want to add verification etc to your mocks, depending on what you're trying to test and your particular style of testing.